# Beginner learning how to resize a simple JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to figure out how to re-size this frame, I plan on animating a clock in the middle of it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;


public class clockMain extends JApplet{

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        JFrame mainPanel = new JFrame("CL0CK");

        mainPanel.setSize(500, 700);
    }

}
```

All Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The most important thing for you to learn, is [how to search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=resize+jframe).  That gives you the answer to almost every problem you'll have, whereas this question only addresses one.

Comment: Start by getting rid of the `extends JApplet` (read [this](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/))

Answer (score -1):

```
 public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        JFrame mainPanel = new JFrame("CL0CK");

        mainPanel.setSize(500, 700);

       // mainPanel.setSize(600, 800);
        mainPanel.repaint();
    }
```

just change the size of mainPanel which is frame .it will be resized

Comment: I tried both of the suggested methods to try to re-size the the frame and got this error each time:java.lang.ClassCastException: clockMain cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I am also using eclipse.